# Download Appium Logs from AppCenter using API or CLI

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-test

I am running appium test from Azure DevOps in Appcenter, After the test is completed I want to download the Appium logs from App Center. Any API or CLI is available to download the Appium Logs from AppCenter

Answer (score 0):

By using this URL was able to get the Appium Logs. This API URL provides all the Logs for a particular test.
[https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/test_runs/{test_run_id}/report](https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/%7Bowner_name%7D/%7Bapp_name%7D/test_runs/%7Btest_run_id%7D/report)